# Disabled Scrollable Textarea

Tags: html

How can I create a scrollable text area which is disabled?  By this I mean, I would like the user to be able to scroll to see the contents of the text area but not be able to edit it.

Comment: it should work in both ie and mozilla

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why use a `<textarea>` if user can't edit it ?

A simple `<div>` would do the trick with fixed height and `overflow:auto;`

Answer (score 24):

I think you need to know the `readonly` property.

```html
<textarea readonly>blabla<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></textarea>
```

Try here : [link](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Chouchen/x9RJu/)

Answer (score 10):

```
<textarea readonly="true"></textarea>
```

just use `readonly` property

Update:

```
<textarea readonly>Some text</textarea>
```

Comment: The `realonly` *attribute* accepts one, and only one, value — `realonly`. `true` is not acceptable.

Comment: Ooops. Typo :) (a) W3Schools is crap. (b) It happens to be OK here, it lists one value — `readonly`, not `true`, not `1`, not `yes` just `readonly`. The example uses `readonly` and the word `true` doesn't appear anywhere on the page.

Comment: +1 for W3Schools. And, yeah, you can even write `readonly="false"` and would still be true :)

Comment: this is correct. however, text can still be selected, so also add css properties to prevent that

Answer (score 4):

the easiest way would be to use "readonly" instead.

another way would be to use a fixed-height div will `overflow:scroll` that looks like a textarea but isn't.